# Cannot Drag jQuery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, slider

I added a jQuery UI slider to my page, but I cannot drag the handle. I found that I had to add display:block to the handle to get it to appear. Otherwise it will not show even though I set the height/width. Here's my CSS:

```
.ui-slider-horizontal {
background:     #eb7c21;
height:         5px;
}

.ui-slider-handle {
background:     url("slider.png") no-repeat;
height:         24px;
width:          27px;
display:        block;
}
```

Comment: I've to agree with @Damien Pirsy — I'm not sure what's your question? Aren't you describing a solution rather than a problem here?

Comment: The problem is that the slider does not slide. The image shows up but when I drag it, nothing happens. There are no javascript errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had to edit the CSS itself then the chances are this problem is with jQuery UI, not CSS. I've never had a problem with slider myself so check the following:

1. Have you got all the correct dependencies for the slider? (i.e. core, widget and mouse)
2. Have you correctly initialized the slider? Just because there are no javascript errors doesn't mean there are no jQuery UI errors.
3. Have you tried the simplest of implementations and worked from there?

I'd copy the source code from the jQuery UI example here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/
If that still doesn't work then show us your whole source (i.e. javascript and html where the slider div is included) and we can have a better shot at helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, and answered, but if you are having this problem the accepted answer of 'you're probably just doing it wrong' is likely less than helpful.

What fixed this issue for me was adding in the image sprite files- I had gotten 404 errors in the console for [css dir]/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png and [css dir]/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png but was trying to get the slider to actually slide before I addressed what I thought was a style issue.

Clearly this is covered by the accepted answer in some sense- but maybe it will save someone a few hours of frustration.

Comment: That is exactly the meaning of "You're probably just doing it wrong".

Comment: No, that's a specific instance of what doing it wrong could be, which others could use as a starting point for understanding what they are doing wrong. That's sort of the whole point of this site right? Otherwise this site could just have 1 answer for all possible issues- 'You're doing it wrong'. But thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: mate, if you would have used '$(window).load()' you had no issue. since you did not, you got the issue you refer to.

Comment: Doesn't even make sense. Best of luck to you friend.

Comment: @stlawrence - My answer offers advise/steps on how to debug this issue regardless of the specifics. It is infinitely more helpful than giving your very specific fix (which the console should have made clear instantly). I'm not sure how you read my answer as "You're probably just doing it wrong" but if anyone else with this issue follows my 3 points they're likely to notice where their problem lies. If you get to SO to look for help before checking console then you are too inexperienced to be using the slider anyway.